# Custom CSS Support for NextJS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am trying to use my custom CSS library for my components in NextJS. In my components, I want to import my custom CSS file but it's not working.

```
import React from 'react'
import '../../style/custom.module.css'

function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className="a b">
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

My custom CSS file is inside the

> style/custom.module.css

I have seen the nextJS documentation their they mentioned that in the NextJS version the custom CSS style is supported by default

Comment: `import styles from './error.module.css'` and use `className={styles.error}`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `css module` you have to import diffrently

```
import styles from '../../style/custom.module.css'


function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.yourcssclassname}>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
-import your css module to the main module.

- and then pass it to the page that requires the css styling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can make a custom Styled component by importing a styled component from @emotion/styled and use this styled component to give styling by making custom components for a particular tag.
You can do this in the same file also outside of your class or in another component also.
To make in the same file, you can do so as:-

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const CustomHeading=styled.h1`
color:yellow;
`
```

Use this Custom heading component in place of the `h1` tag.

To define Custom component in the different file you will define with the same method, but you need to import that Custom component in the file in which you need to import it as:

`import CustomHeading from "File path"`
After that, you can use this component in place of your `h1` tag.